# Multipage Jquery mobile page - how to run a different function depending on the page who's loaded (pagecontainerbeforeload?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[image: https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t1.0-9/10013746_10152357263748463_7802091576467407720_n.jpg]

```
<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#page03' ,function(){
        drawTimeLine(3);
    });
</script>
```

I'm developing an app in jQuery Mobile and I'm pretty new to it.

I am using a multipage html and I want when the page who's id is "page04" loaded, to `drawTimeLine(value)` with a value=4 and when the page with id "page03" to the value for the `drawTimeLine(value)` to be 3 and so on…

I've tried for more than a week and still haven't succeeded.

If I understood correctly from the JQM api – I should use `pagecontainerbeforeload` in some way.
If some more code is needed, please tell me and I'll reupload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function () {
    pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id'); 

    if (pageId === 'index') {
        alert('Page index');
    }

    if (pageId === 'second') {
        alert('Page second');
    }    
});
```

**pagecontainershow** will trigger when every page is ready to be shown. Then you need to get page ID and do something during each page execution. Of course there are  other page events but you need this one if you want to draw something.

This code used to be easier but latest page handling widget changed things a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I've tried it but it doesn't work for some reason.
It does work when after I get to the wanted page, I reload it...
any ideas?
is the fact that i'm using a canvas in the same spot for all 4 "timelines" may have something to do with that?

Comment: This would make sense only if you have more then one HTML page? So do you have only one or several HTML pages?

Comment: Then this should work, if it is working in my case it should also in yours.But lets do it a little bit different. Mail me your project and I will fix it for you.

Comment: Bless you!
what is your mail?

Comment: dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Comment: How did you solve it? :) I'm working with jQuery Mobile last few years and I never had a problem with canvas elements, at least nothing like this? :D

Comment: the problem was as always between the computer screen and the chair (me). I've put the variables of the drawTimeLine as global valiables. When I moved them inside the function - problem was solved....